# Magento 2 Custom Module Insert Data Issue

Tags: magento2, admin, database, magento-2.1, crud

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

I'm making a custom module. For developing custom module i'm taking reference of Magento CMS Module `{folder path}\magento2\vendor\magento\module-cms`

I have below code while INSERT data in the database.

**{folder path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\Save.php**

```
public function execute() {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {

        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Custom\Module\Model\Posts');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('posts_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'module_posts_prepare_save', ['post' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
        );

        try {
            $model->save();
            echo "Done";
            exit;
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved this Post.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['posts_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the post.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['posts_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('posts_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

I have enabled DB Query Log. `{folder path}\magento2\var\debug\db.log`. Instead of INSERT query, it's executing UPDATE query.

It always print UPDATE query in the log file, so INSERT query is not executing. Don't know what's wrong.

**Temporarily** i'm doing this, but it's not perfect solution. Issue with INSERT only, Update/Edit is working fine

```
if ($id) {
    $model->save();
} else {
    // START MANUAL SAVE DATA
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $this->_resources->getConnection();

    $themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('<table_name>');
    $sql = "<INSERT QUERY>");";
    $connection->query($sql);
    // END MANUAL SAVE DATA 
}
```

Comment: I believe posts_id should be automatically created, what if you skip/comment these lines:   
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('posts_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

Comment: Nope. Checked. That's not the case. It's same code as CMS Module. I just changed as per my modules requirement for configuration

Answer (score 2):

i was facing same problem while trying to save data but further i use this code to save and it was working fine.

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('<module_name>/<controller_name>/new');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Model\<model_name>');


        if (isset($data['item_id']) && $data['item_id'] == '') {
            unset($data['item_id']);
        }

        $rowData->setData($data);

        $rowData->save();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Item has been successfully saved.'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: This is Default Magento 2 Way but it's not working in my case.

Answer (score -1):

create a Controller action for the module.

```
namespace <Namespace>\<Modulename>\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Let’s Create a simple Block file for our Module

```
<?php
namespace <Namespace>\<Modulename>\Block;
class <Blockname> extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```